# React Native with react-navigation and Redux - How to implement globally available 'Sign Out' button

Tags: javascript, react-native, redux, react-redux, react-navigation

I've created a React Native app with navigation provided by *react-navigation*, also integrating redux with *react-navigation-redux-helpers*, and I'm trying to figure out a good way of implementing a globally-available '*SignOutHeaderButton*' component that, when pressed, will dispatch a redux action and perform a navigation operation.

At the moment, I'm having to pass a function via *screenProps* from the application root component, which is the function that dispatches the redux action. This function is then passed to the *UpdatesListView* container component via *screenProps*, and is then passed into the *SignOutHeaderButton* common component as a prop via *navigationOptions*.

Is there a better way in which I can implement this so that I don't have to pass any props into the *SignOutHeaderButton* component and without having to instantiate a *signOut()* function within each container component in the application from which there will be a '*Sign Out*' button?

**App.js:**

```
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';
import { reduxifyNavigator } from 'react-navigation-redux-helpers';
import { PersistGate } from 'redux-persist/integration/react';
import { Provider, connect } from 'react-redux';

import { appContainer } from './src/navigators';
import { store, persistor } from './src/store/configureStore';
import { signOut } from './src/actions/auth';

const app = reduxifyNavigator(appContainer, 'root');

const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return {
        state: state.navReducer
  }
}

const AppWithNavigationState = connect(mapStateToProps)(app);

export default class App extends React.Component {

  signOut() {
    store.dispatch(signOut());
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Provider store={store}>
        <PersistGate loading={null} persistor={persistor}>
          <AppWithNavigationState
            screenProps={{
              signOut: this.signOut
                }} />
        </PersistGate>
      </Provider>
    )
  }
}
```

**UpdatesListView.js:**

```
import React from 'react';
import { View, Container, Content, Text, Button } from 'native-base';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

import SignOutHeaderButton from '../components/common/SignOutHeaderButton';

class UpdatesListView extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  static navigationOptions = ({ navigation }) => {
    return {
      headerTitle: 'Updates',
      headerRight: <SignOutHeaderButton signOut={navigation.getParam('signOut')} />
    }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.navigation.setParams({
      signOut: this.props.screenProps.signOut
    })
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Container>
        <Text>UpdatesListView</Text>
      </Container>
    )
  }
}


const mapStatetoProps = state => {
  return {
        updates: state.updatesReducer,
        tags: state.tagsReducer
  }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(UpdatesListView);
```

**SignOutHeaderButton.js:**

```
import React from 'react';
import { Button } from 'react-native';
import { withNavigation } from 'react-navigation';

class SignOutHeaderButton extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  signOut() {
    this.props.signOut();
    this.props.navigation.navigate('AuthStack');
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Button
        title="Sign Out"
        onPress={this.signOut} />
    )
  }
}

export default withNavigation(SignOutHeaderButton);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use redux connect, the idea of redux connect is to bind the `store` `dispatch` `state` to your component `this`, When you use redux connect you can access any redux store `dispatch` and `state` from anywhere in your application this works for both react and react-native, for example for **SignOutHeaderButton.js:**

```
import React from 'react';
import { Button } from 'react-native';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { withNavigation } from 'react-navigation';

class SignOutHeaderButton extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  signOut() {
    this.dispatch(signOut());
    this.props.navigation.navigate('AuthStack');
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Button
        title="Sign Out"
        onPress={this.signOut} />
    )
  }
}

export default connect()(withNavigation(SignOutHeaderButton));
```

Also, you can pass the redux store state to your component by passing a function to your `connect(/*your function*/)` to resolve the state data you want.
for better understanding, you can try this tutorial: https://blog.logrocket.com/react-redux-connect-when-and-how-to-use-it-f2a1edab2013

**Note** using nested smart components is very common, redux connect has a very smart algorithm to compare the store state changes, please check this: https://hackernoon.com/why-using-nested-connect-react-redux-components-is-good-bd17997b53d2 
[image]

Comment: Shouldn't a child component such as SignOutHeaderButton be 'dumb', unaware of the redux store and only relying on what it receives from props?

Comment: Yes, it will work, but connecting child components to the redux store is an anti-pattern, is it not? Only the container component should be smart

Comment: No, actually this is the main purpose of redux, if your component is a dump component it should only act as a design template not more or less no actions and no state access.

Comment: Okay, so while the SignOutHeaderButton is a child component, it is still acceptable practice to make it a smart component?

Comment: Yes I am sure 100%

Comment: Okay, thanks for the explanation. Didn't first think it was acceptable.